# Selenium Builder use of conditionals

Tags: selenium, builder

I'm using Selenium Builder for testing porpuses, but I'm not able to find anything in the docs about how to use conditional statements.

For example, if a element is present do A, if not do B. I know how to add or remove a "verify" step or a "store" step, but not how to use the values as a condition.

I need exactly the JSON format Selenium builder offers, so I don't contemplate using other tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is not something that's supported by Selenium Builder:
[Issue Link](https://github.com/SeleniumBuilder/se-builder/issues/7)